# Numerically Computing the eigenvector of a large sparse matrix when the eigenvalue is known

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

I am running numerical simulations on large, sparse, Markov matrices $P$ and want to understand the steady state equilibrium of said Markov matrices.

Since these matrices are Markov, all the columns sum to a value of $1$, and by definition they have an eigenvalue of $\lambda_{max} = 1$. Now upon building these matrices in Matlab, I find that they are very ill-conditioned so when I run `eigs(P, 1)` I am told that the computation to find the eigenvalue numerically either does not converge, or I get a largest eigenvalue that is close to, but not exactly, $1$ such as $.98$.

I have also tried in Matlab to perform null space calculations on the matrix difference `null(P-eye(n))`, however for large matrices this operation tends to run out of memory.

Is anyone aware of any numerical programs or techniques (particularly using Matlab) that can efficiently compute the null space or eigenvector of a space matrix, with respect to memory?

Comment: Do you have any idea about the other eigenvalues? Are they close to 1 in magnitude?

Comment: If the value $\lambda=1$ has multiplicity $1$ you might be able to use iteration. Does matlab have a sparse matvec ?

Comment: @Laray as of now we don't know, however thats actually a future topic of research that we are looking into for our specific Markov matrices.

Comment: @kimchilover what do you mean by matvec? As of now I believe it is multiplicity $1$, however it could change as I move to more complex examples

Comment: I mean, does matlab have a utility for multiplying a sparse matrix by a vector, in time proportional (say) to the number of non-zero entries in the matrix?

Comment: You might try [shifted inverse iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration). If you store your matrix as a sparse matrix, MATLAB can probably do the system solves efficiently. But, as others have said, if there are multiple eigenvectors with eigenvalues near to 1, finding the exact eigenvector corresponding to 1 will be hard.

Comment: Since the columns all sum to $1$, the vector whose components are all $1$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. Hence this one eigenvector is immediate. Do you really need to solve the far more general problem?